# Show 2 DB Tables in One DataTable List In MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I've looked at a bunch of different sites that talk about showing two SQL Server tables in one view model, but haven't really found what I was looking for.

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

I have 2 SQL Server tables that have a SQL Server View setup to show fields from both tables (linked by a ProjectID). One table shows Project submission details and the other shows work being done on the Project.

I want to show all the fields from the SQL Server View in one Datatable on a view model and I also want to be able to perform CRUD operations on this Datatable. The link below shows an example of what I'm trying to do.

I should add that what I will be developing is basically a work tracker that's web-based within my company. This will have a list of projects, possibly up to 300 lines, and this list will need to be able to scroll vertical and horizontal so the user doesn't have to scroll through a long page. They also want this list to have a sort feature and be searchable. This is why I chose the DataTable, but I'm open to any other possibility that can deliver the features I'm looking for.

Thank you for your time and any advise you can offer!

[Datatable Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLnOe.png)

Comment: How are you accessing the sql view?  If you are using Entity Framework, I would think scaffolding would give it to you automatically.

Comment: I would be using EF database-first implementation. But I wasn't sure if the scaffolding would allow me to insert, update, and delete using a SQL View instead of a SQL Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you got one model as

```
model x
barcode 
Manufacturer
Model
```

the second is .

```
model y 
building 
room no
qty
```

now from dal to presentation you can use tuples

ie

```
tuple dbValue<model x,model y> = new tuple<model x, model y>(xObj,yObj);
```

ojects are values from db as model x object and model y object 
in presentation layer you may create your viewmodel as

```
model vm

public string barcode{get;set;}

public string Manufacturer{get;set;}

public string Model{get;set;}

public string building {get;set;}

public string room {get;set;}

public string qty{get;set;}
```

now transfer the values as

```
vm obj = new vm(dbValue.Item1.barcode,dbValue.Item1.Model,dbValue.Item1.Manufacturer,dbValue.Item2.building ......so on);
```

use thiis object for the view
more about tuples https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt493248.aspx